# Use NDSolve to solve a PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following PDE (a master equation, and $P$ is probability density, $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le1$):

$$
\partial_t P(x,y,t)=x\partial_xP(x,y,t)+(1-y)\partial_yP(x,y,t)+2P(x,y,t)
$$

The initial conditions are $P(x,y,t=0)=\delta(x-0.05,y-0.85)$. For the boundary conditions, if the probability density is going to flow through the boundary, I won't do anything to stop it. (**How to express the BC in Mathematica?**)

I used the following command:

```
NDSolve[{D[P[x, y, t], t] == 
x D[P[x, y, t], x] + (1 - y) D[P[x, y, t], y] + 2 P[x, y, t], 
P[x, y, 0] == DiracDelta[x - 0.05, y - 0.85]}, P, 
{t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

First, Mathematica gave the following warning:

```
Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of 
independent variable y. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>
```

Moreover, the result it gave obviously is wrong:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[(P[x, y, t] /. %) /. {t -> 0}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**My question is**: 1) How can I express the boundary conditions I mentioned 2) How can I make the `NDSolve` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specific example can be solved by `DSolve`. First let's get the general solution of the PDE:

```
gsol = DSolve[{D[p[x, y, t], t] == 
               x D[p[x, y, t], x] + (1 - y) D[p[x, y, t], y] + 2 p[x, y, t]}, p, {x, y, t}]
```

> ```
> {{p -> Function[{x, y, t}, C[1][x (-1 + y), t + Log[x]]/x^2]}}
> ```

Then substitute it into the boundary condition:

```
eqn = p[x, y, 0] == DiracDelta[x - 0.05, y - 0.85] /. gsol[[1]]
```

> ```
> C[1][x (-1 + y), Log[x]]/x^2 == DiracDelta[-0.05 + x, -0.85 + y]
> ```

Solve for `C[1][_, _]`:

```
Solve[Cases[eqn, C[1][a__] -> a, Infinity] == {p1, p2}, {x, y}]
Solve[Simplify[eqn /. %, {p1, p2} ∈ Reals][[1]], C[1][p1, p2]]
bc = % /. (a_[b__] -> c_) -> (a -> ({b} \[Function] c))
```

> ```
> {{x -> E^p2, y -> E^-p2 (E^p2 + p1)}}
> {{C[1][p1, p2] -> E^(2 p2) DiracDelta[-0.05 + E^p2, 0.15 + E^-p2 p1]}}
> {{C[1] -> Function[{p1, p2}, E^(2 p2) DiracDelta[-0.05 + E^p2, 0.15 + E^-p2 p1]]}}
> ```

Substitute it back to the general solution:

```
 sol[x_, y_, t_] = (p[x, y, t] /. gsol /. bc)[[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> (E^(2 (t + Log[x])) DiracDelta[-0.05 + E^t x, 0.15 + E^-t (-1 + y)])/x^2
> ```

BTW, when exploring this I encountered another problem, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55537/1871) for details.

Comment: What is `condition` in the last Mathematica input?

Comment: @wdg It's `bc`, I forgot I changed the name, edited, thx for pointing out :)