# DSolve breaks when the ordering of independent variables aren't proper?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 3.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2**

---

I encountered this when trying to solve [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55530) with `DSolve`:

```
eqn = With[{p = p[x, y, t]}, D[p, t] == x D[p, x] + (1 - y) D[p, y] + 2 p]; 
DSolve[eqn, p, {t, x, y}]
```

> DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions.

> ```
> (* Input returned *)
> ```

It's not surprising to see `DSolve` fails in solving PDEs… but why this warning? Even more shocking:

```
DSolve[eqn, p, {x, y, t}]
```

> ```
> {{p -> Function[{x, y, t}, C[1][x (-1 + y), t + Log[x]]/x^2]}}
> ```

The result changed just because I reordered the independent variables (from `{t, x, y}` to `{x, y, t}`). Is this a bug?

Comment: Very odd indeed; on mathematica 10 the first request is returned unevaluated.

Comment: @chris Yeah, v9.0.1 and Wolfram Programming Cloud returned unevaluated after the warning, too.

Comment: With *Mathematica* 5.2 I get exactly the same result ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PfqUC.png)) as with versions 8.0.4 and 10.4 (OS Windows 7 x64). So the bug seems to be quite old...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The bug has already been introduced in v3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx2uD.png Version 2.1 isn't influenced, because `DSolve` can't seem to solve PDE at that time: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Se1.png

Comment: Have you reported the bug to the support?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I can't remember… I believe I have, but can't find the relevant e-mail. Not sure if it's because the support doesn't reply.

Comment: If you change the second argument from `p` to `p[x, y, t]` you get a solution in a different form (in V12). It seems to solve the pde as if you had written `p[t, x, y]` instead of `p[x, y, t]`; since it returns an expression, the permutation of the arguments does not matter and you get a valid solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Funny, and the behavior actually varies from _v3_ to _v5_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifxMj.png So perhaps someone attempted to fix the bug in the early days, but the result isn't that great.

Comment: I think the problem here is that one of p for DSolve is outside With[ ], so author asks for pure function solution. Compare to  With[{p = p[x, y, t]}, 
 DSolve[D[p, t] == x D[p, x] + (1 - y) D[p, y] + 2 p, p, {t, x, y}]], which behaves as expected

Comment: @user18792 Yeah, that's what Michael E2 observed in his comment, and I think this should not be called a _problem_, because a single `p` rather than `p[x, y, t]` is valid and documented.

Comment: @xzczd Yes I, of course, agree. The usage of With[ ], however is not a best way to demonstrate this bug.

Comment: @user18792 I think writing PDE with `With` is more readable. Actually this isn't orignal sample, I edited it yesterday. (You can check the edit history. ) I've edited the sample further, now it should be better.

Comment: Now it is indeed much better.

Comment: `I reordered the independent variables` The order of `independent variables` must match the order they appear in the dependent variable. At least this is what I always made sure when I type the call. So if you write `u[x,y,t]`, then it should be `{x,y,t}` also and if you write `u[t,x,y]` then it should be `{t,x,y}`.

Comment: @Nasser Well, it's WRI that should fix the bug, or at least add proper warning and document if they finally decide to treat this behavior as a feature, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with you that in theory the order should not matter, but I noticed long time ago that the order must match between how the variables appear in the dependent variables and in the call to `DSolve`. I just assumed it is by design. I do not think I've seen this documented anywhere if my memory is right. btw, in Maple, one does not even have to tell `dsolve` what is the dependent variable and what are the independent variables. It figures them out by parsing the ODE or the PDE itself.

Comment: @Nasser Just tested the first 10 PDE examples in `DSolve` document. (Didn't test them all because it's really painful to do this on Wolfram cloud… ) The order matters in 5 of them. (3, 4, 6, 8, 10. )

Comment: Yes, the order matter but as you noticed, it is not all the time. There are cases where order does not matter. That is why I try to keep same order all the time. Please see [why-dsolve-gives-different-answer-depending-on-order-of-variables-ux-t-vs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206069/why-dsolve-gives-different-answer-depending-on-order-of-variables-ux-t-vs) where I said at the top `and ordering the variables the same elsewhere`

Comment: There was also a bug in NDSolve posted recently where the order made mattered https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215945/unexpected-switch-of-partial-derivatives-when-differentiating-interpolatingfun/216021#216021