# Why DSolve gives different answer depending on order of variables: $u(x,t)$ vs. $u(t,x)$?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Using V12 on windows 10.

I would think it should not matter if one uses $u(x,t)$ or $u(t,x)$ in the specification of the PDE, as long as everything else is consistent (keeping the initial condition correct, and ordering the variables the same elsewhere). Right?

The same PDE solution should result.

Why in this case Mathematica gives different solution when using $u(x,t)$ vs. $u(t,x)$?

### Using $u(t,x)$

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, sol]; 
pde = D[u[t, x], t] + (1/(x^2 - 1))* D[u[t, x], x] == 0; 
ic = u[0, x] == 1/(1 + (x + 3)^2); 
sol = u[t, x] /. First@DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[t, x], {t, x}];
solAtZer0 = (sol /. t -> 0);
Plot[solAtZer0, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Using $u(x,t)$

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, sol]; 
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + (1/(x^2 - 1))*D[u[x, t], x] == 0; 
ic = u[x, 0] == 1/(1 + (x + 3)^2); 
sol = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
solAtZer0 = (sol /. t -> 0) // Simplify;
Plot[solAtZer0, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug or there something wrong I am doing?

Btw, both solutions seem to be wrong actually.  Since at $t=0$ the solution should be the given initial condition, which is in both cases is the same:

```
  Plot[ 1/(1 + (x + 3)^2), {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the question here is why the solution given changes so much depending on order of variables.

**Update:**

This problem is from class textbook. Peter J. Olver, into to PDE's. Page 26

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Comment: Hm, smells like a bug - have you tried checking with `NDSolve` if that has the same issue?

Comment: @user21  NDSolve gives correct initial conditions, yes. But with lots of warnings. I could not get NDSolve to give correct result for long period of time as well. I think I need more specialized options for it which I am not sure what they should be now. I tend to use `DSolve` much more than `NDSolve` for school work.

Comment: The solution of the equation in any case will not be unique, since there are no boundary conditions. Add bc and everything will be in place,  just there will be no analytical solution:)

Comment: @AlexTrounev  No boundary conditions are needed, if the solution space is the entire half-plane, `t >= 0`.  In this case, the method of characteristics solves this PDE without boundary conditions.

Comment: @user21  Because solutions to this PDE flow along characteristics, `NDSolve` will not give the desired solution at points with characteristics emanating from a boundary instead of `t = 0`.

Comment: @user21  In addition, the problem appears to be ill-posed, as shown in the last part of my answer.

Comment: hi @bbgodfrey, you said "the problem appears to be ill-posed". OK. But this problem is from our textbook. Please see Peter J. Olver, into to PDE's. Page 26. I'll add screen shot of the problem now. Book gives screen shots of the solution with time, but book does not show the analytical solution itself. Only screen shots of the solution.

Comment: Eq. 2.24 in the book you cited is not the same as the PDE in your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey you are correct. When I copied the PDE, by mistake, I typed minus sign instead of plus. But still, the main question remains the same, why changing from $u(x,t)$ to $u(t,x)$ changes the solution. That is really all what I am asking.

Comment: Both answers are correct at `t = 0` but for different ranges of `x`.  Please see the discussion just before the addendum in my answer.  Evidently, `DSolve` cannot handle transitions among the three different expressions for the solution, which occur at time-dependent values of `x`.

Comment: The sign change shown in the text eliminates the problematic kink in the characteristics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, both answers are correct, but only for restricted ranges of `{x, t}`.  To see what is happening, solve this PDE without initial or boundary conditions to obtain the general solution,

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] + (1/(x^2 - 1))*D[u[t, x], x] == 0;
sol = DSolveValue[pde, u[t, x], {t, x}]

(* C[1][1/3 (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)] *)
```

In other words, an arbitrary function of `s == x^3 - 3 t - 3 x` satisfies the PDE.  (Reversing the order of the arguments of `u` yields an equivalent result.)  The initial condition specified in the question is applied by expressing it in terms of `s /. t -> 0` as follows.

```
solvx = Solve[s == x^3 - 3 x, x] // Flatten
(* {x -> -(2^(1/3)/(-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3)) - (-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3)/2^(1/3), 
    x -> (1 + I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3)) 
        + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3))/(2 2^(1/3)),
    x -> (1 - I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3)) 
        + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-s + Sqrt[-4 + s^2])^(1/3))/(2 2^(1/3))} *)
```

(Of couse, only the real branches can be used, because `x` is real.)  For now, substitute them all into the initial condition and replace `s` by its definition.

```
sol == Map[1/(1 + (x + 3)^2) /. # &, solvx] /. s -> x^3 - 3 x - 3 t
(* {1/(1 + (3 - 2^(1/3)/(3 t + 3 x - x^3 + Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3) 
        - (3 t + 3 x - x^3 + Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3)/2^(1/3))^2), 
    1/(1 + (3 + (1 + I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (3 t + 3 x - x^3 + 
        Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3)) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) 
        (3 t + 3 x - x^3 + Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3))/(2 2^(1/3)))^2), 
    1/(1 + (3 + (1 - I Sqrt[3])/(2^(2/3) (3 t + 3 x - x^3 + 
        Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) 
        (3 t + 3 x - x^3 + Sqrt[-4 + (-3 t - 3 x + x^3)^2])^(1/3))/(2 2^(1/3)))^2)} *)
```

Plotting this at `t = 0` yields

[image]

Comparing this curve with the third plot in the question, we see that the correct represention of `IC` in terms of these formal solutions. is

```
Piecewise[{{sol[[1]], x < -1}, {sol[[3]], -1 <= x <= 1}, {sol[[2]], x > 1}}];
```

which, when plotted at `t = 0`, yields the third curve in the question.

To return to the first sentence in this answer, the first solution in the question corresponds to  `sol[[1]]` but only for `x <= -1`, and the second solution in the question to `sol[[2]]` but only for `x >= 1`.  So, this is a bug, but fixing it may not be trivial.

**Addendum: PDE/IC is ill-posed**

Because the solution is constant along curves of constant `s`, it is useful to plot those curves.

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate@Table[(x^3 - 3 x - s)/3, {s, -10, 10, 1}], {x, -4, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, t}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}],
    Plot[(x^3 - 3 x + 2)/3, {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]]
```

[image]

The black line corresponds to `s = -2`.  Curves for `s > -2` in the region `-2 < x < 1` are pathological in that they intersect `t = 0` in two places, and the values of `IC` are not the same in those places.  So the solution is undefined there.  Also, for `x > 2` there is a discontinuity at the `s = -2` curve, because the solutions on either side propagate from values of `IC` that are not at adjacent values of `x`.  Here are examples for `t = 1`

```
Plot[Evaluate[Piecewise[{{sol[[1]], x < -1 || fx[t][[2]] < x < fx[t][[3]]}, 
    {sol[[2]], x > fx[t][[3]]}}] /. t -> 1], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {"x", "sol"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

and for `t = 2`

```
Plot[Evaluate[Piecewise[{{sol[[1]], x < fx[t][[1]]}, {sol[[2]], x > fx[t][[1]]}}]
    /. t -> 2], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {"x", "sol"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

where

```
fx[t_] := Solve[x^3 - 3 x + 2 == 3 t, x, Reals] // Values // N // Flatten
```

One would not expect `NDSolve` to handle this PDE and initial condition well.

Comment: And if you add the boundary conditions?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Because the PDE is first order in `x`, only one boundary condition would be needed.  And, since the characteristics flow from left to right, as in my second plot, that boundary condition should be on the left.  Doing so would not eliminate the strange behavior shown in my answer, unless the boundary condition were at `x = 1` or larger.